# Add icon to tab in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am trying to add an icon to a tab in android and it isnt working.

here is part of my code, im not sure what is wrong

```
th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.thbodyview);
th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.Front);
    specs.setIndicator("Front",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_one));
    th.addTab(specs);
```

When I run the app the tab just says "Front" and there is no icon, if someone could fix it that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: what px dimensions is your drawable

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked over a year ago, but I shall provide an answer anyway, as it might be helpful to others wanting to know how this is possible.

The following code will enable you to retrieve the `TextView` and `ImageView` that form the title / heading of each tab (defined in the standard `layout/tab_indicator.xml` layout file):

```
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    View currentTab = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(areaIndex);
```

or to get the view of the current tab that's in view:

```
    View currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
```

Then to actually get the Text and Image views:

```
    TextView tabTitleField = (TextView) currentTab.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

    ImageView tabTitleIcon = (ImageView) currentTab.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    tabTitleIcon.setImageResource([specify your drawable resource here]);
```

Padding can be programmatically added to the `ImageView` using

```
tabTitleIcon.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
```

to add spacing between the title and the icon.